# Display callback array in UITableView, currently showing as empty

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I have a function that connects to an endpoint and returns a `JSON` result which I save into an array and using a callback function. Everything seems to be configured correctly. But no data is showing in the tables when the simulator runs. I'm not sure why? I was under the impression I would just need to run `tableView.reloadData()` but this doesn't do anything

```
class ViewConversionsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    /* codesToConvert: The Country code and Country sent from the previous view used to connect to the endpoint
     * arraysToDisplay: The total list of countries and their corresponding values to be displayed
     */
    var codesToConvert = [String]()
    var arraysToDisplay = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        calculateRate(value: codesToConvert) {(structuredArray) in
            self.arraysToDisplay.append(contentsOf: structuredArray)
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func calculateRate(value: [String], completionHandler: @escaping (_ structuredArray: [String])->()){

        var structuredArray = [String]()

        let url = URL(string: "domain.com")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "pairs=\(value[0] + value[2])&pairs=\(value[2]+value[0])"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) in
            do  {

                var arrayToSend = [String]()

                let jsonResult = try  JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)
                let results = jsonResult as! [String: Any]
                for values in results{
                    arrayToSend.append(values.key)
                    arrayToSend.append("\(values.value)")
                }
                arrayToSend.append(value[1])
                arrayToSend.append(value[3])

                // Structure the array to the required format
                structuredArray.append(arrayToSend[1] + " " + String(arrayToSend[0].prefix(3)))
                structuredArray.append(arrayToSend[4])
                structuredArray.append(arrayToSend[3])
                structuredArray.append(arrayToSend[5] + " · " + String(arrayToSend[2].prefix(3)))

                completionHandler(structuredArray)

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }



    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arraysToDisplay.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100.0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ConversionsCell

        cell.Amount1.text = arraysToDisplay[0]
        cell.currencyName1.text = arraysToDisplay[1]
        cell.Amount2.text = arraysToDisplay[2]
        cell.currencyName2.text = arraysToDisplay[3]

        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should've reloaded the tableview inside the completion block.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   calculateRate(value: codesToConvert) {(structuredArray) in
      self.arraysToDisplay.append(contentsOf: structuredArray)
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
         tableView.reloadData()
      }
   }   
}
```

Comment: Error: UITableView.reloadData() must be used from main thread only, UITableViewController.tableView must be used from main thread only

Comment: Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UITableViewController tableView]
PID: 99931, TID: 3928363, Thread name: (none), Queue name: NSOperationQueue 0x7f7f9480d580 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED), QoS: 0

Comment: Ayy perfect! Thank you

Comment: You can accept the answer if you find it helpful. Cheers.!

Answer (score 0):

This is occurred because your tableView load the data when the data network call process haven't completed yet.

put your tableView.reloadData inside the closure and it must be on main thread. So it should be like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   calculateRate(value: codesToConvert) {(structuredArray) in
      self.arraysToDisplay.append(contentsOf: structuredArray)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
   }   
}
```